# Best outdoor bike storage?

Tags: storage

I live in a small town home and have limited indoor bike storage. The space that I do have outdoors is too small for products like the tidy tent. Any recommendations?

Comment: If you use a tarp, arrange it so that air can circulate under it, to keep condensation from building up.

Comment: @ojs When you see a duplicate, you can use the *flag* feature, as I am doing now :-)